# iterate through on click function javascript

Tags: javascript

I have function which is called onclick event, but inside I have for loop and I would like to store a counter value, so on each click I will be able to iterate to another file

```
 var canvas;
 var viewer = new JSC3D.Viewer(canvas);

  function loadModel()
  {
    var filename = document.getElementById("hidden_file_path").innerHTML;
      var components=['something1.stl', 'something2.stl'];
       for  ( var i=0; i<components.length; i++  ) 
       {
         viewer.replaceSceneFromUrl(components[i]);
       }
    viewer.update();
  }
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assumin that you call loadModel on click.

```
var canvas;
var viewer = new JSC3D.Viewer(canvas);
var counter = 0;
var filename = document.getElementById("hidden_file_path").innerHTML; // where are you using filename?
var components=['something1.stl', 'something2.stl']; 

  function loadModel()
  {
    viewer.replaceSceneFromUrl(components[counter]);
    counter++;
    viewer.update();
  }
```

Hope this solves the problem